# Is it possible to delete branch deep link with the Android Branch IO SDK?

Tags: android, deep-linking, branch.io

I'm generating deep links from branch.io to an android app. Is it possible to delete or deactivate a deep link programmatically, from my app using the [Branch IO Android SDK](https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/android-sdk-overview)? I couldn't find anything like that in the documentation.

Thanks for any help guys.

Comment: I am not sure this is what you want or not but you can put some check before set deeplink.

Comment: Hi Pranav. What I really want is, after one client opens the deep link and click yes on a confirmation dialog, when this deep link is clicked on a client I can know that this deep link was already used and are not valid anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Branchster Here-

**Update [23/04/2020]-**

Access Tokens are now available on all customers' dashboards

Also, we have recently changed the API syntax on how to delete deep links and will update the document soon. Based on the recent change, you use the following API for deleting existing links.

```
curl -X DELETE \
'https://api2.branch.io/v1/url? url=https://example.app.link/delete&app_id=YOUR_APP_ID' \
-H "Access-Token: YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

Please note that you require an access token for this. Currently, you can not delete links through the Branch SDK.

I'll keep this post updated with any future changes.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Kartik. But, there is not even a way to change the parameter values from a deep link using the Android SDK?

Comment: Hi @bmelocarcalho currently you can not do this through our SDK.

Comment: Hi @KartikShandilya - I wrote your support because of exactly this, but there's no answer yet. The current branch.io website doesn't allow me to upgrade to the Enterprise solution, the only thing happening is a chat bot window that just ends the conversation after a few questions. I don't see the access token in the dashboard and therefore can't delete links via the API, and updating the $desktop_url for existing links doesn't work properly. I'm a bit lost.. Thank you for an answer!

Comment: @KartikShandilya I have generated the access toke but getting `400 bad request` `Authentication failed !` Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, you cannot delete a Branch.io Link programmatically but however, you can easily delete the said link in their dashboard which requires no coding whatsoever. So I think it defeats the purpose, since Branch.io links are meant to be managed in their dashboard.